# How to achieve windows authentication in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

We are  implementing a website in APS.NET MVC4 which has to run on intranet. We got a requirement for windows authentication with Active Directory (LDAP). When i change the authentication mode to windows from Forms , application logging automatically without explicit username and password from login page.

How to achieve windows authentication, in which the logon page which accept the username and password and should validate?
Please provide me if there are any examples...any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to be confused about what Windows Authentication is.

Answer (score 1):

You could leave FormsAuthentication enabled and then add the following membership provider:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="YOUR AD CONNECTION STRING" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and then:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="MY_ADMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="MY_ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

Comment: No, it will be forms authentication but the authorization logic will use Active Directory to authenticate and authorize users because of the custom membership provider.

Comment: @user1952461 Windows Authentication means that it uses your windows login to authenticate against an application. They log in to their windows machine / domain and since they are authenticated that way, they don't need to log in to a website since it trusts the account.

Answer (score 0):

The method you did already seems to be correct.

In windows authentication, you will get logged automatically if you try to load the page from the same machine. However it will ask for the windows credentials if you try to login from a different machine.